# Nature of a large systems of first order coupled PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-equations

My actual equations are the dynamic equations of a Cosserat rod, which is of the form

$$\frac{\partial{U}} {\partial{t}}+B\frac{\partial{U}} {\partial{s}}+c=0$$

where $t$ denotes time, $s$ denotes the spatial variable and $U$ is an $18 \times 1$ vector of dependent variables and $B$ is a constant $18 \times 18$ matrix given by

$$B=\left[\matrix{O & O & O & O & O & O\\ O & O & O & O & O & O\\O & O & O & O & I & O\\O & O & O & O & O & I\\O & O & P & O & O & O\\O & O & O & Q & O & O}\right]$$

where

\begin{align}
O&=\left[\matrix {0 &0 &0\\0 &0 &0\\0 &0 &0}\right], \quad P=10^{7}\left[\matrix {1.02 &0 &0\\0 &1.02 &0\\0 &0 &2.65}\right] \\
I&=\left[\matrix {1 &0 &0\\0 &1 &0\\0 &0 &1}\right], \quad Q=10^{7}\left[\matrix {2.65 &0 &0\\0 &2.65 &0\\0 &0 &1.02}\right]
\end{align}

and $c$ is a vector of nonlinear functions of the unknowns $U$.

The first two rows in $B$ are completely zeros, which means the first six equations do not have any spatial derivatives and so are ODEs. I would like to know the nature of the system of equations.

**What I have done**

I have found the eigenvalues of the matrix $B$ (using MATLAB)

\begin{align}
&[3194.9, -3194.9, 5151.5, -5151.5, 5151.5, -5151.5, 3194.9, \\
&-3194.9, 5151.5, -5151.5, 3194.9, -3194.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
\end{align}

All the eigenvalues are real, but not distinct (4 eigenvalues have a multiplicity of 3 each, and one eigenvalue has a multiplicity of 6).

Some text books say that if the matrix $B$ is diagonalizable, then the system will be *hyperbolic*, and if all the eigenvalues are real and distinct, the system is *strictly hyperbolic*.

Using MATLAB, I computed

$$[V,D]= \text{eig}(B)$$

and MATLAB says $V$ is of full rank but the determinant is very low ($-1.4 \cdot 10^{-20}$). Can I say that my system is **hyperbolic**?

If yes, which numerical method is suitable for this system? Can I use any explicit finite difference scheme?

Comment: If it wasn't for $c$, this would be easily solvable. If $c$ were independent of $U$, it would be reasonably solvable. But you say $c$ is a non-linear function of $U$. That makes talking about solutions much harder. I think you'll need to give more information about $c$ before anyone can discuss this in a useful manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely hyperbolic since eigenvalues of $B$ are real, but it is not strictly hyperbolic. Such an hyperbolic system of balance laws can be solved numerically by using *operator splitting* (Godunov splitting, Strang splitting, etc.), which consists in alternating between the integration of
$$
\partial_t U + B\, \partial_s U = 0
\tag{A}
$$
and
$$
\partial_t U + c = 0
\tag{B}
$$
The linear system of conservation laws (A) can be solved using e.g
the [Lax-Friedrichs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) or [Lax-Wendroff](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method) schemes. The evolution equation (B) can be solved using the Euler method or other Runge-Kutta schemes for instance.

---

RJ LeVeque, *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*, Cambridge University Press, 2002. [doi:10.1017/CBO9780511791253](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253)

Comment: Hello @EditPiAf, Is there any good reference to learn these splitting methods which is relatively easy to understand as well. I would like to know how we can get a solution using (A) and (B). Thank you.

Comment: @sreejathsivaj Sure: RJ LeVeque, *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*, Cambridge University Press, 2002. [doi:10.1017/CBO9780511791253](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253)